# What Lego set does this belong to?

Tags: part-identification

I want to find which LEGO set this unusual piece belongs to. I have 10? I have a few sets from the late 1980's and the rest are from the 1990's.  I have looked and looked. Hope you can help!

[image]

It looks like a 1 x 1 square brick with six studs extended 1/4". The studs have a square lip around it. The brick base has two studs and then there is a square with four studs that fits around it to make six!

The color seems to be closest to Medium Blue or Medium Azure

Comment: That looks very unusual for a LEGO piece. Are you able to locate the LEGO logo or a number?

Comment: I don't recognize this as LEGO either - looked at Clikits and Znap and none of it matches what you have. Also, the 1/4" and 1" sizes you mention are very unlike LEGO. Do you have any examples of pieces that fit with this piece? Pictures would be great.

Answer (score 13):

That isn't Lego, it's Construx by Fisher-Price. I had some of those :)

http://www.thisoldtoy.com/fisher-price/dept-7-playsets/f-construx/nuts.html

[image]

Comment: Thank you SirRobin. You have solved my mystery! Now I can let go of it! I have been on so many sites trying to find what set it is from. I really didn't even consider that it wasn't a Lego.